# Adapting GIF size to browser window dimensions using CSS

Tags: html, css, gif

I would like to embed a GIF in a website so that it changes size to adapt to different browser window sizes. The following code works when the src = .jpg, but when I use src=.gif the code breaks. How can this code be adjusted to work with a GIF?

Here is the HTML end

```
<a href="#" class="image"><img src="myimage.gif" alt="" data-position="25% 25%" /></a>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <h2>Title here</h2>
                                    <p>Description here.</p>
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Here is the CSS end for the class

```
/* Image */

    .image {
        border-radius: 0.25em;
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

        .image img {
            border-radius: 0.25em;
            display: block;
        }

        .image.left, .image.right {
            max-width: 40%;
        }

            .image.left img, .image.right img {
                width: 100%;
            }

        .image.left {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 1.5em 1em 0;
            top: 0.25em;
        }

        .image.right {
            float: right;
            margin: 0 0 1em 1.5em;
            top: 0.25em;
        }

        .image.fit {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 0 2em 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .image.fit img {
                width: 100%;
            }

        .image.main {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 0 3em 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .image.main img {
                width: 100%;
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could demo with your actual images?

Comment: @Paulie_D the issue exists for any animated gif. For instance: https://media.giphy.com/media/olAik8MhYOB9K/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is to add some width and height on your container/parent tag (in the case ".image"), then size the img inside the container to 100% of his parent element:

```
.image {
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

    width: 40vw;
    height: 30vh;

    overflow:hidden;
}
.image img {
    display: block;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```